# How to execute an animation, wait 5 seconds, then do it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple tile. Upon click, the tile gets filled in with content B instead of content A, and on click again, the tile gets filled back in with content A instead of content B.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(".switch").on('click', function() {
  toggleBrand($(this));
})

function toggleBrand(_this) {
  _this.children().not(".no-display").toggle();
  _this.children(".no-display").toggle();
}
```

What I would now like is for the second "click" to happen automatically. I.e., when you click the object, content B shows instead of A, then there's a 2 second delay, and content A shows instead of content B again without you having to click.

I tried using a `setTimeout` as below:

```
$(".switch").on('click', function() {
  _this = $(this)
  toggleBrand(_this);

  setTimeout(toggleBrand(_this),2000); 
})
```

But the fiddle breaks with a `setTimeOut undefined` even though I cased it correctly... Am I not using `setTimeout` correctly?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v018hh52/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using setTimeout wrong

You are passing the return value of the function, instead you should pass a function.

```
$(".switch").on('click', function() {
  _this = $(this)
  toggleBrand(_this);

  setTimeout(function() { toggleBrand(_this) },2000);

  // OR, thanks @4castle for his comment
  setTimeout(toggleBrand, 2000, _this);
})
```

Explanation

```
function foo() { return "value" };

foo // -> function
foo() // -> "value"
```

Comment: `setTimeout` allows you to specify parameters to the function after you set the delay, so you could do `setTimeout(toggleBrand, 2000, _this)` (Doesn't work on IE 8 and under, meh)

Answer (score 2):

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v018hh52/5/

All you needed to do was fix your `setTimeout` call :(, basically you provide setTimeout with a function which will call your function, if you provide your function like you are doing at the moment it will be called asap instead of in 2000 (2 seconds)

So just change your `setTimeout` call to look like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    toggleBrand($this)
  }, 2000);
```

And that should do the trick. Also I updated your CSS, because you keep clicking it will highlight the content and then you can no longer see it.

P.S. also you may want to set a flag when you run this code as the user can keep clicking on the div and it will get the `setTimeout` in a puzzle. Also if this content is generated from another script you may want to make a global event listener on 'document'

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to webdeb's answer you could also bind the parameter to the function like this:

```
setTimeout(toggleBrand.bind(null, _this), 2000);
```

Or completely remove the `_this` parameter and just use `this` in the `toggleBrand` function this way:

```
setTimeout(toggleBrand.bind(_this), 2000);
```

With the `toggleBrand` function implemented as:

```
function toggleBrand() {
  this.children().not(".no-display").toggle();
  this.children(".no-display").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Make sure to specify how this would change what `toggleBrand` should look like. (Remove the underscores)

Comment: This is the way to do it since he needs `this` variable to be the passed thing not a parameter.

Comment: @4castle no change at all needed, the other answers would need changes, not this one thought. OP uses `this` variable not a parameter variable

Comment: @Akxe The OP's code uses `_this.children()` where `_this` was a parameter.

Comment: @4castle Thanks, I added a snippet for toggleBrand